# Capacitated Facility Location in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

We are trying to configure Optaplanner to solve a Capacitated Facility Location problem where each depot has a fixed capacity, as already provided by [ESRI Network Analyst](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/location-allocation.htm).

I have defined the following entities:

- DepotLocation - a potential location in which a depot can be built
- Depot - a depot with a planning variable DepotLocation
- DemandLocation - a demand point with a weighting

So far we have managed to optimise the location of the depot based on where the demand is with some success.  We do this by minimising the total distance between each demand point and it's nearest depot.  However, this often results in some depots being assigned way more demand than others. The next step is to add the option to balance the demand so that each depot is allocated roughly the same amount.

We have tried adding an additional planning variable to assign each demand location to a specific depot, with using hard scores to prevent overloading the depots. However, we have struggled to prevent this getting stuck in local optima.

Has anyone tried to solve this or a similar problem with Optaplanner before, or can anyone give any advice as to how best solve this kind of problem?

Thanks

Comment: I've implemented [the facility problem](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/coursera-discrete-optimization/tree/master/dis-opt-knapsack/src/main/java/be/ge0ffrey/coursera/faculty/domain) once with OptaPlanner as an experiment. I got pretty good results, it's pretty straightforward. It's not my cleanest code, but it might be inspirational.

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet. This looks pretty close to what we've got but there are some key differences that we would like to check out. I'll let you know if we have any success!